# Reading XML: How to catch exceptions from ticpp::LoadFile()?

Tags: c++, xml, file-io

I am trying to read a XML file using ticpp::LoadFile(); It was not successfull and I did not know why because I have no idea how to catch the exceptions. Here is what I did:

```
try
{
    // Load a document
    ticpp::Document doc( pFilename );
    doc.LoadFile();

    // Get an element by chaining calls - no return values to check, no TiXmlHandle
    ticpp::Element* pElem = doc.FirstChildElement()->NextSibling();

    // do something useful here
}
catch( ticpp::Exception& ex )
{
    // If any function has an error, execution will enter here.
    // Report the error
    std::cout << ex.what();
}
```

But I the ex actually shows grayed as if it is never declared. I am wondering how I can catch the exceptions in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was the file path that is messed up. 
The code itself is fine.